# Can see Featured Image Meta Title on admin dashboard but no options to add image

Tags: wordpress

I can see the title Featured Post on admin page but when I click and try to add image I can't see any option to add image.

I tried adding add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); in functions.php of the theme. 
[This is how I see admin dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzo24.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the Plugin Advanced Custom Fields Pro. Removing the Plugin solved the issue.

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8872